# How to display error from validate() in appended rows

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hi I am having trouble displaying the error message from validate() function in my controller. as suggested to me, i put this

```
@if ($errors->any())
{{dd($errors->all())}}
@endif
```

and send the form.

the result of dd is

```
array:2 [▼
0 => "The product_name.0 field is required."
1 => "The product_name.1 field is required."
]
```

now my problem is how can I put that in my dynamic rows?

here's my initial table row,

```
<td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type='text' data-type="product_name" id='product_name_1' name='product_name[]' for="1" readonly>
    @if ($errors->has('product_name.0')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('product_name.0') }}</p> @endif                
</td>
```

here's my jQuery append script

```
 var rowCount = 1;
 $('#add').click(function() {
    rowCount++;
    $('#saleItems').append('<tr id="row'+rowCount+'"><td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type="text" data-type="product_name" id="product_name_'+rowCount+'" name="product_name[]" for="'+rowCount+'"readonly/>@if($errors->has("product_name.'+rowCount+'"))<p class="help-block">{{$errors->first("product_name.'+rowCount+'") }}</p> @endif </td></tr>');
});
```

also I am not sure if my php IF condition is being recognize inside the append rows.

can you help me please? thank you so much in advance!

Comment: are you submitting data using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

As jquery cannot read laravel's blade template directives, you will need to put them outside the single quotes.

Try this: (not tested)

```
$('#saleItems').append('<tr id="row' + rowCount + '"><td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type="text" data-type="product_name" id="product_name_' + rowCount + '" name="product_name[]" for="' + rowCount + '"readonly/>'+@if($errors->has(+ 'product_name.' + rowCount + ))'<p class="help-block">{{$errors->first("product_name.' + rowCount + '") }}</p>' + @endif '</td></tr>');
```